# How do I distribute a Scala macro as a project?

Tags: scala, maven, macros, sbt

Suppose I have a Scala compile-time macro that I find useful and would like to share it (I do).  How do I create a JAR file that when loaded into another project would execute the macro when compiling the new project?

Specifically, I've made a `StaticAnnotation` that rewrites the AST of the class that it wraps before compile time.  This works in my Maven build (macro defined in the `main` directory, runs on test cases in the `test` directory) because I have

```
<compilerPlugins>
    <compilerPlugin>
        <groupId>org.scalamacros</groupId>
        <artifactId>paradise_2.10.5</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-M5</version>
    </compilerPlugin>
</compilerPlugins>
```

in my `scala-maven-plugin`.  (I'm starting with a Scala 2.10 project and if it works, will provide both 2.10 and 2.11.)

But if I put the resulting JAR on a Scala console classpath, in a Scala script, or into another Maven project (without special compiler plugins), it simply *ignores* the macro: the AST does not get overwritten and my compile-time `println` statements don't execute.  If I use the `@compileTimeOnly` annotation on my macro (new in Scala 2.11), then it complains with the `@compileTimeOnly` error message.

Do I really need to tell my users to add compiler plugins in their `pom.xml` files, as well as alternate instructions for SBT and other build tools?  Other packages containing macros ([MacWire](https://github.com/adamw/macwire), [Log4s](https://github.com/Log4s/log4s)) don't come with complicated build instructions: they just say, "point to this dependency in Maven Central."  I couldn't find the magic in their build process that makes this work.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're relying on a macro-paradise-only feature then yes, you do need to tell your users to add compiler plugins. See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html . The projects you mention are only using the scala compiler's built-in (non-paradise) macro features, not macro annotations.